# How to extract a zip file using ssh2

Tags: php, libssh2

I am trying to extract a ZIP file using SSH2 but I am not having much luck.

I have tried this code:

```
$connection = ssh2_connect("localhost", 22);
if(ssh2_auth_password($connection, "user", "pass"))
{

$unzip = "unzip /directory/to/file/file.zip";
ssh2_exec($connection,$unzip);

}
```

but it doesn't do anything. Although, when I type the command directly into the terminal/command prompt, it works perfectly.

How can I get this to work?

Thanks!

Comment: Is `$createFolder` supposed to be `$unzip`?

Comment: you have forgot to pass the $unzip in `ssh2_exec` function. use that.

Comment: Sorry, I re-created the code and accidentally forgot to change $createfolder to $unzip folder. I have edited my question. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You should first send the file using

[ssh2_scp_send()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.ssh2-scp-send.php)

and then you can use unzip:

ssh2_exec($connection, "unzip /path to zip/ -d /location where you want to unzip/"); //syntax error